# How is the conversion being done in this C code?

Tags: c, string, unsigned

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void printlength(char *s, char *t) {
    unsigned int c=0;
    int len = ((strlen(s) - strlen(t)) > c) ? strlen(s) : strlen(t);
    printf("%d\n", len);
}

void main() {
    char *x = "abc";
    char *y = "defgh";
    printlength(x,y);
}
```

---

When I compile it, it gives **3**, but, I don't understand how the conversion is taking place here: **(strlen(s) - strlen(t)) > c)**

Comment: This is very poor code `(strlen(s) - strlen(t))` is _always_ >= 0 as it is unsigned math.

Comment: So the optimizer could translate to `printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(s) );`

Comment: @M.M unless strings where the same length, then `printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(t) );`

Comment: @chux if they are the same length then `strlen(t)` can be replaced by `strlen(s)`

Comment: @M.M Well yes!  Your optimizing compiler brain exceeded mine on that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very poor code `(strlen(s) - strlen(t))` is *always* >= 0 as it is unsigned math.  The type returned by `strlen()` is `size_t`, some unsigned type.  So unless the values are equal, the difference is always a positive number due to unsigned math wrap-around.

Then `int len = strlen(s);` even when the length of `s` is differ from `t`.

The better way to use similar code would be to only add.

```
// ((strlen(s) - strlen(t)) > c) 
(strlen(s) > (c + strlen(t))
```

---

Note: On rare platforms with `SIZE_MAX <= INT_MAX`, the difference can be negative as math is then done with the *signed* type `int`.  Yet the compare with `c` is `unsigned` and than then happens as `unsigned` resulting in a negative difference being "wrapped-around" to a very large number, greater than 0.  [@Paul Hankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639887/how-is-the-conversion-being-done-in-this-c-code/42639919#comment72407457_42639919)

Comment: Always? What if SIZE_MAX <= INT_MAX?

Comment: @PaulHankin No difference, as the negative subtraction result is still promoted to unsigned by virtue of comparison against `unsigned int` variable

Comment: @PaulHankin the type used in the subtraction is not affected by the type of   `c` so the difference is always >= 0.  The resulting compare will be applied to the wider of `size_t` and `unsigned`.   Although not specified, never came across a platform with a wider `unsigned` than `size_t` - perhaps some 64-bit graphics processor might employ your premise.

Comment: Further on @PaulHankin premise `SIZE_MAX <= INT_MAX`, then the subtraction _would_ go through integer conversions `int` math.  Yet the compare would happen with `unsigned math` and have the same result.

Comment: @chux I don't think so. If int is wider than size_t, they'll be promoted to int, not to unsigned, just as unsigned char's in expressions are promoted to int, not unsigned. So the subtraction in that case would be signed. MM is right that in saying that this makes no difference to the code, since c is `unsigned int` and the signed result from the subtraction would be converted to unsigned. You're definitely right that this is not a practical concern, since there's no platform with wider int than size_t.

Comment: @PaulHankin Looks like we arrived a similar conclusions.

Comment: @chux Thanks for the explaination :) Just one doubt "The code is comparing signed and unsigned, which is actually signed being typecasted to unsigned and hence the comparison becomes true". Am I right now ?

Comment: @Barry There is no type casting (e.g. `(int)`)  There are _type conversions_  according to the integer promotions.  The compare `>` takes the type of the left side (`size_t` or rarely `int`) and the right side (`unsigned`) and promotes one side to the higher ranking of the other, which is certainly `size_t` or `unsigned`.  In any case, the compare is done with some unsigned math.